# How to test a controller in an application which uses compile time injection

Tags: scalatest, playframework-2.6

My application uses compile time injection. The loader is defined as follows (code snippet):

```
class AppLoader extends ApplicationLoader { ...}

class AppComponents (context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) {
...

//within this I have created instances of my controller and created a route
    lazy val userController = new UserController(userRepository, controllerComponents, silhouetteJWTProvider)

lazy val router = new Routes(httpErrorHandler, homeController,userWSRoutes, countController,asyncController, assets)

}
```

The `UserController` class has a `signupUser` `Action`

```
@Singleton
class UserController @Inject()(
userRepo: UsersRepository,cc: ControllerComponents, silhouette: Silhouette[JWTEnv])(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc){
...

def signupUser = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async{ implicit request => {
...
}
}
```

I want to test the `signupUser` `Action` but I don't know how to do it. I have created the following spec class but I am stuck at how to write the spec and test it.

```
class UserControllerSpec extends PlaySpec {


    "User signup request with non-JSON body" must {
      "return  400 (Bad Request) and the validation text 'Incorrect body type. Body type must be JSON'" in {

//I want to create instance of a `FakeRequest` annd pass it to UserController.signupUser. I should test a Future[Result] which I should then assert.

//How do I get instance of userController which I created in my Apploader? I don't want to repeat/duplicate the code of AppLoader here.

      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existing components from your `ApplicationLoader` can be [directly instantiated within tests](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTestingWithComponents#Using-existing-components). Mixin [WithApplicationComponents](https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play/blob/f2e06257a5ac456bb79e6f5a4916eb0efeee9e82/module/src/main/scala/org/scalatestplus/play/components/WithApplicationComponents.scala#L18) trait and override `def components: BuiltInComponents`:

```
override def components: BuiltInComponents = new YourComponents(context)
```

Here is an example implementation of your test:

```
import org.scalatestplus.play._
import org.scalatestplus.play.components.OneAppPerSuiteWithComponents
import play.api.BuiltInComponents
import play.api.mvc.Result
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._
import scala.concurrent.Future

class UserControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuiteWithComponents {

  override def components: BuiltInComponents = new YourComponents(context)

  "User signup request with non-JSON body" should {

    "return  400 (Bad Request) and the validation text 'Incorrect body type. Body type must be JSON'" in {

      val Some(result): Option[Future[Result]] =
        route(
          app, 
          FakeRequest(POST, "/signup").withJsonBody(Json.parse("""{"bad": "field"}"""))
        )

      status(result) mustBe BAD_REQUEST
    }
  }
}
```

[`Helpers.stubControllerComponents`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/8ef9e47e1d0d877730a57d6b7d4312fe925bff92/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L586) is very useful for unit testing controllers. Here is an example of how it can be used to implement the same test without having to deal with `ApplicationLoader`.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import controllers.UserController
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatestplus.play._
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._

class UserControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with MockitoSugar {

  "User signup request with non-JSON body" should {

    "return  400 (Bad Request) and the validation text 'Incorrect body type. Body type must be JSON'" in {

      implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
      implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

      val controller = new UserController(
        mock[UsersRepository]
        Helpers.stubControllerComponents(playBodyParsers = Helpers.stubPlayBodyParsers(materializer)),
        mock[Silhouette[JWTEnv]]
      )

      val result = 
        call(
          controller.signupUser, 
          FakeRequest(POST, "/signup").withJsonBody(Json.parse("""{"bad": "field"}"""))
        )

      status(result) mustBe BAD_REQUEST
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mario. I just tried your code but faced several issues. I think I am facing name conflicts. I am seeing errors like `Cannot resolve symbo Helpers`,`cannot resolve symbol playBodyParsers`,`Cannot resolve symbol JWTEnv`. Interesting, when I hover the mouse over `JWTEnv`, the IDE recommends that I import the correct file `components.SilhouetteComponents` where `JWTEnv` is defined but importing it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I am also confused about using `new YourComponents(context)` when overriding `components`. In my code, I already have `AppComponents` defined `class AppComponents (context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)`. I tried to do `override def components: BuiltInComponents = new AppComponents(context)` but I get the error `cannot resolve symbol AppComponent`.

Comment: Mario - I was able to make the first test case work by adding line `package app;`  in my `Apploader.scala`. However, I am not sure if this is the right thing to do. Could you please confirm? Basically the `AppLoader.scala` is in `projectdir/app/` while my specs are in `projectdir/test/ControllerSpec/UserController.spec`. Now the compiler can find my `AppComponent` class created in `AppLoader.scala`. Did I solve the problem correctly?

Comment: There are no hard rules here. `import` clause is [not required](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/packages-and-imports.html#imports) for accessing members of the same package. This includes tests, that is, a test in the same package as the entity being tested, will have access to that entity without requiring an `import` statement even though the test is under a separate `test/` directory. One popular convention is to have test package structure under `test/` mirror the package structure under `src/`.

Comment: Thanks. I opened another issue for this - check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739913/class-is-not-visible-unless-i-declare-it-in-a-package/50741490?noredirect=1#comment88490790_50741490