# Class is not visible unless I declare it in a package

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest, playframework-2.6

I have a class `AppComponents` in `AppLoader.scala` in `projectDir/app`

My tests are in `projectDir/test/ControllerSpec/UserControllerSpec.scala`

In `UserControllerSpec.scala`, I tried to create an instance of `AppComponents` but the compiler couldn't find the `AppComponents` class

```
override def components: BuiltInComponents = new AppComponents(context) //doesn't compile
```

But if I include statement `package app` in `Apploader.scala` then the compiler is able to find `AppComponents` and the above code compiles.

I don't understand this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Top-level definitions outside a packaging are assumed to be injected into a special empty package. That package cannot be named and therefore cannot be imported. However, members of the empty package are visible **to each other** without qualification.](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/09-top-level-definitions.html)

So `AppComponents` should only be visible to other classes/traits/etc. outside a package. Because

> if I include statement package app in Apploader.scala then the compiler is able to find AppComponents

it looks like `UserControllerSpec` does declare a package and can't see the empty package's members.

This behavior is probably for consistency with Java, see answers to [Import package with no name Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645950/import-package-with-no-name-java).

Comment: Alexey, you Genius! Yes. UserControllerSpec is in a package!

Comment: I'll add that I don't think there's ever a good reason not to have a package declaration in a Scala file. In Java you could want to simplify directory structure, but in Scala you can have both.

Comment: There was an interesting side-effect which I didn't observer earlier. If I declare my `Apploader` class in a package then obviously I'll have to access it using `packagename.classname`. I realised it later. I had to change entry in `application.conf` to `play.application.loader="app.AppLoader"`